# RxJs 5 - TreeShaking with webpack 4

Tags: webpack, rxjs, rxjs5, webpack-4

I'm using `RxJS 5.5` and I'm importing operators like:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
```

Since I upgraded webpack 3 -> 4, I see that whole `rxjs` package is imported:

[image]

Seems like aliases configuration in webpack no longer work:

```
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
resolve: {
  alias: rxPaths(),
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
},
```

Comment: This as been discussed intensively here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3018